# In Windows, what actually is the clipboard?

Tags: windows, clipboard

This may sound like a silly question, but what actually is the clipboard?

My curiosity spiked after I noticed that the clipboard is used in more complex ways than I first thought possible. I thought the clipboard basically kept track of either a string of text, an image or a file and then simply would paste whatever if it had into the wherever the user specified if the context matched.

However, with word processing software like Microsoft Word I've noticed that you can copy and paste styles straight from websites and that on programs like Skype you can copy quotes that appear to be normal text in a Notepad document, but are actually formatted notes in Skype's UI.

I looked at the source code for a fake Skype quote generator, and it appears that there are multiple clipboards. Or is the clipboard laid out in a key-value type map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple [clipboard data formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and when you [SetClipboardData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you specify which format the data is. You can set multiple clipboard formats simultaneously because the clipboard is cleared explicitly with [EmptyClipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), You can also register your own custom formats to be used between your applications.

The other side opens the clipboard, looks which formats there currently are, chooses the most appropriate one, and proceeds accordingly.

Comment: I think it's important to point out that the clipboard is not only a static place where data (even in multiple formats) can be stored, but that it's also possible to tell Windows "there is something in the clipboard, and if somebody wants to see it, let me know". Then basically nothing is stored in the clipboard, only this "note" - and only when you paste it, the clipboard owner produces the required data in the required format. That's also why for example Word will ask you when you exit with a lot in the clipboard whether you want to keep it (because then it would have to be materialized).

Comment: This is actually a very useful optimization: Assume you copy or cut a lot of data in Word. Word doesn't need to create a physical copy of that data and put it into the clipboard. So when you paste it in Word again, Word knows it's an "internal operation" and can move around your information in an internal, more optimized way (for example, it can create a copy of an image by referencing the old one internally instead of copying all pixels). Only if you paste it outside into an application which doesn't know about any of this, an actual copy in the required format is created.

Comment: @CherryDT: Yes, thanks for adding this. It's just that the OP seemed to asked specifically about the multiple formats issue, despite the general title, so I kept it simple... :)

Answer (score 2):

To add to @ybungalobill answer, read the rest of the information that is available at the Windows Dev Center [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649012(v=vs.85).aspx). A quick excerpt of the CUT/COPY operations is -

> To place information on the clipboard, a window first clears any previous clipboard content by using the EmptyClipboard function. This function sends the WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD message to the previous clipboard owner, frees resources associated with data on the clipboard, and assigns clipboard ownership to the window that has the clipboard open. To find out which window owns the clipboard, call the GetClipboardOwner function.
>
> After emptying the clipboard, the window places data on the clipboard in as many clipboard formats as possible, ordered from the most descriptive clipboard format to the least descriptive. For each format, the window calls the SetClipboardData function, specifying the format identifier and a global memory handle. The memory handle can be NULL, indicating that the window renders the data on request. For more information, see Delayed Rendering.

You can follow up on the function definitions in the API reference if you so choose.But SetClipboardData is the function where magic happens.